# how to loop through json object to get key and value, and display them in angular html?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, angular

I need to build an email sender by using `nodemailer`. I am sending the json object below and want to display the previous and current value changes with a pair of key and value in angular html.

**<json input>**

```js
async function showChanges(formdata){
    let htmlFile = await fs.promises.readFile(templatePath, {
      encoding: "utf-8",
    });

    let template = handlebars.compile(htmlFile);

    let templateInput = {
      Message_Body: {
        Previous: formData.Message_Body.formChanges.Previous,
        Current: formData.Message_Body.formChanges.Current,
      }
    };
    return template(templateInput);
}
```

For example, imagine the formData input looks like:

```json
    "Message_Body": {
        "formChanges": {
            "Previous": {
                "Events": "TEST",
                "AdditionalInfo": ""
            },
            "Current": {
                "Events": "TEST111",
                "AdditionalInfo": "test"
            }
        }
    }
```

And the html structure in angular looks like:

```js
<div>
  <h3>Title: This following has been changed!</h3>
  
  <h3>Previous Values</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>{{item.key}} : {{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

  <h3>Current Values</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>{{item.key}} : {{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I loop through the previous and current keys and values and display them as a list?
I am assuming `*ngFor` should be used in `<div>` tag but it looks like it is applicable only in case of an array..

Can anyone give me any clue please?

I tried adding this code `*ngFor="let item of templateInput | keyvalue"` to the following:

```html
<div>
  <h3>Title: This following has been changed!</h3>
  
  <h3>Previous Values</h3>
  <ul *ngFor="let item of Message_Body.Previous | keyvalue">
    <li>{{item.key}} : {{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

  <h3>Current Values</h3>
  <ul *ngFor="let item of Message_Body.Current | keyvalue">
    <li>{{item.key}} : {{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the result is nothing shown (empty)..
My expected result should be:

```
Title: This following has been changed!

Previous Values:
* Events: TEST
* AdditionalInfo: 

Current Values:
* Events: TEST111
* AdditionalInfo: test
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in your `templateInput` object, you are nesting the `Message_Body` object inside another object with the key `Message_Body`. This means that in your Angular template, you should access the `Previous` and Current objects using the nested `Message_Body.Message_Body.Previous` and `Message_Body.Message_Body.Current` paths. To fix this, you can simply remove the outer `Message_Body` key from your `templateInput` object:

```
let templateInput = {
  Previous: formData.Message_Body.formChanges.Previous,
  Current: formData.Message_Body.formChanges.Current,
};
```

Secondly, in your Angular template, you should use the `templateInput` object as the data source for the `*ngFor` directive, not the `Message_Body.Previous` and `Message_Body.Current` objects directly. Here's how you can modify your template to loop through the key-value pairs and display them:

```
<div>
  <h3>Title: This following has been changed!</h3>
  
  <h3>Previous Values</h3>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of Previous | keyvalue">{{item.key}}: {{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

  <h3>Current Values</h3>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of Current | keyvalue">{{item.key}}: {{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I put "previous" and "current" both out of the "Message_Body" scope. Next, I used *ngFor .. but still, nothing is displayed.. Is *ngFor used only for an array (not json object), isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by using `#each` and `lookup` helpers in `handlebars.js`.
I have opened up another ticket. If anyone wonders the question, please feel free to take a look at the below URL:

[how to iterate multiple arrays by using handlebars and #each to display values in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75867103/how-to-iterate-multiple-arrays-by-using-handlebars-and-each-to-display-values-i/75867659#75867659)