# how to iterate multiple arrays by using handlebars and #each to display values in a table?

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I have three arrays as follows.

```
['Name', 'Gender']
['Jason', 'Male']
['Jenny', 'Female']
```

The below is a part of the code I made and those arrays are nested in the input json obj:

```js
let htmlFile = await fs.promises.readFile(templatePath, {
   encoding: "utf-8",
});

let input = {
   header: ['Name', 'Gender'],
   previous: ['Jason', 'Male'],
   current: ['Jenny', 'Female']
}

let template = handlebars.compile(htmlFile);

return template(input);
```

This is the template html:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th>BEFORE</th>
     <th>AFTER</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     {{#each header}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{this}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
     {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the current result:

|  | BEFORE | AFTER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name |  |  |
| Gender |  |  |

What should I put inside of `<td></td>` to result in the below?

|  | BEFORE | AFTER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Jason | Jenny |
| Gender | Male | Female |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the [lookup](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) built-in helper to lookup the value at the current [@index](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#index) on the `previous` object for the first column and the `current` object for the second.

The code becomes:

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(`
  <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <th></th>
       <th>BEFORE</th>
       <th>AFTER</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       {{#each header}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{this}}</td>
          <td>{{lookup ../previous @index}}</td>
          <td>{{lookup ../current @index}}</td>
        </tr>
       {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
`);

const input = {
  header: ['Name', 'Gender'],
  previous: ['Jason', 'Male'],
  current: ['Jenny', 'Female']
};

const output = template(input);

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wonderfully it works as expected. Thank you so much!